# How do the RoutedCommand constructors differ from eachother?

Tags: wpf, routedcommand

The RoutedCommand in WPF has 3 overloaded constructors.

Consider the following:

```
public static RoutedCommand AddTextFieldCommand = new RoutedCommand();
```

vs

```
public static RoutedCommand AddTextFieldCommand = new RoutedCommand("AddTextField", typeof(DesignerWindow));
```

What advantage does the second one have?

Does it make it easier to define in XAML ? MSDN doesn't really give much
details about the second constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, there's no real semantic difference between the two. For me, they both seem to function exactly the same. I won't say definitively that there isn't a difference, I just haven't noticed one.

However, what I have noticed is that at least using the constructor that allows you to add a name, and adding a useful name, can *really* help with debugging. At a break point where you're handling routed commands you can much more easily tell which command it is if all of your commands have names.

--
HTH,
Dusty